# How can I get make JavaScript code execution to wait until an AJAX request with script is loaded and executed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, callback

In my application, I am using `Ext.Ajax.request` to load scripts which I execute with `eval`.

The problem is that since it takes time for the AJAX request to complete, code that is executed afterward which needs variables which are in the script loaded in via AJAX. In this example, I show how this is the case. How can I change this code so that the execution of the JavaScript after the AJAX waits until the script in the AJAX call has been loaded and executed?

**testEvalIssue_script.htm:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('2. inside the ajax-loaded script');
</script>
```

**main.htm:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadViewViaAjax(url) {
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: url,
                    success: function(objServerResponse) {
                        var responseText = objServerResponse.responseText;
                        var scripts, scriptsFinder=/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+)<\/script>/gi;
                        while(scripts=scriptsFinder.exec(responseText)) {
                            eval.call(window,scripts[1]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            console.log('1. before loading ajax script');
            loadViewViaAjax('testEvalIssue_script.htm');
            console.log('3. after loading ajax script');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

**output:**

```
1. before loading ajax script
3. after loading ajax script
2. inside the ajax-loaded script
```

**How can I get the output to be in the correct order, like this:**

```
1. before loading ajax script
2. inside the ajax-loaded script
3. after loading ajax script
```

Comment: Put 2. where 3. is and put 3. where 2. is?

Comment: Call a function after the AJAX request completes and show a 'Loading..' message to the user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous, that means that the ajax call is dispatched but your code keeps on running as happy as before without stopping. Ajax doesn't stop/pause execution until a response is received. You'll have to add an extra callback function or something like that.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadViewViaAjax(url, callback) {
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: url,
                    success: function(objServerResponse) {
                        var responseText = objServerResponse.responseText;
                        var scripts, scriptsFinder=/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+)<\/script>/gi;
                        while(scripts=scriptsFinder.exec(responseText)) {
                            eval.call(window,scripts[1]);
                        }
                        callback.call();
                    }
                });
            }

            console.log('1. before loading ajax script');
            var afterAjax = function(){
                console.log('3. after loading ajax script');
            }
            loadViewViaAjax('testEvalIssue_script.htm', afterAjax);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the ajax call is asynchronous, if you want to execute something that depends on data loaded via ajax, you will have to execute it in the success method. Put the code in another method, and then call that method after the eval statements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function doSomeAmazingThings() {
                // amazing things go here
            }

            function loadViewViaAjax(url) {
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: url,
                    success: function(objServerResponse) {
                        var responseText = objServerResponse.responseText;
                        var scripts, scriptsFinder=/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+)<\/script>/gi;
                        while(scripts=scriptsFinder.exec(responseText)) {
                            eval.call(window,scripts[1]);
                        }
                        doSomeAmazingThings(); 
                        console.log('3. after loading ajax script');
                    }
                });
            }

            console.log('1. before loading ajax script');
            loadViewViaAjax('testEvalIssue_script.htm');
        </script>
```

Comment: Yes, but to be clear you really should show the third console statement either moved into the callback or into your new fake function. As shown it is still rather confusing to someone who does not understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making the AJAX call synchronous... Of course you'd have to stop using the Ext.Ajax library, but it's worth it if you need ajax results before your next line of code.

That's how my intranet pages communicate with my database. There's a setback I've discovered, in that you can't see any page updates until Javascript relinquishes control back to the page, so things like a status bar, a progress bar or overlay are impossible with synchronous Ajax (Not true for my firefox, it updates even inside synchronous code in some circumstances).

I use this - it's a bit home-grown and messy, but it's worked flawlessly for years in my circle. Just create a new AJAX(), set the url, add queries (name/value pairs) as needed, set asynchronous to false, and when you call Execute from a function, it will block until the Ajax returns.

Or, if you want to use it asynchronously, just write a new "onready" function for tha AJAX object you create, and change asynchronous to true.

I wrote this many years ago, so it's not the neatest, and there are ways to do things differently, but it works as a primer, and you can tweak it however you like without having to depend on another library.

```
function AJAX(){

//Declarations
    var thisExt=this; //To be referenced by events

//Initialize Properties
    thisExt.URL="";
    thisExt.Query="";
    thisExt.Method="GET";
    thisExt.Asynchronous=true;
    thisExt.Encoding="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    thisExt.PostData="";

// Provide the XMLHttpRequest class for IE 5.x-6.x:
// Other browsers (including IE 7.x-8.x) ignore this
//   when XMLHttpRequest is predefined
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest == "undefined") {
    try { 
        thisExt.XMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); 
    }
    catch (e1) {
        try { thisExt.XMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); }
        catch (e2) {
            try { thisExt.XMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
            catch (e3) {
                try { thisExt.XMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
                catch (e4) {
                    throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    thisExt.XMLHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
}


//Methods
    thisExt.XMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(thisExt.XMLHTTP.readyState==4){
            window.status="";
            thisExt.onready(thisExt);//Passes thisExt so that the callback will have assess to the entire object, not just the returned text.
        }else{
            window.status=thisExt.XMLHTTP.readyState;//Just for debugging
        }
    }
    thisExt.addQuery=function(name,value){
        if(thisExt.Query!=""){
            thisExt.Query+="&"
        }
        thisExt.Query+=encodeURIComponent(name)+"="+encodeURIComponent(value)
    }

//Not really necessary, you could just say AjaxObj.URL="bla bla"
    thisExt.setURL=function(URL){
        thisExt.URL=URL;
    }
//Not really necessary, you could just say AjaxObj.Query="bla bla"
    thisExt.setQuery=function(Query){
        thisExt.Query=Query;
    }
//Not really necessary, you could just say AjaxObj.Method="bla bla"
    thisExt.setMethod=function(Method){
        thisExt.Method=Method;
    }
//Not really necessary, you could just say AjaxObj.Encoding="bla bla"
    thisExt.setEncoding=function(Encoding){
        thisExt.Encoding=Encoding;
    }
//Not really necessary, you could just say AjaxObj.PostData="bla bla"
    thisExt.setPostData=function(PostData){
        thisExt.PostData=PostData;
    }

    thisExt.Execute=function(){
        if(thisExt.URL==""){
            alert("AJAX.URL cannot be null.")
            return;
        }
        var URL2=thisExt.URL;
        if(thisExt.Query!=""){
            URL2=URL2+"?"+thisExt.Query;

        }
        if(thisExt.Method=="POST"){
            //this.XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",this.Encoding);
            thisExt.XMLHTTP.open("POST", URL2, thisExt.Asynchronous);
            thisExt.XMLHTTP.send(thisExt.PostData);
        } else {
            thisExt.XMLHTTP.open("GET", URL2, thisExt.Asynchronous);
            thisExt.XMLHTTP.send(null);
        }
    }

//Events & callbacks
    thisExt.onready=function(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by creating an `XMLHttpRequest` object and calling the [open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) function with the async parameter set to false.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", false);
var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
```